# Классическая задача теории вероятностей

Tags: статистика, теория, теория-вероятностей

Задача:

> На стеллаже библиотеки в случайном порядке расставлено 15 учебников, причем пять из них в переплете. Библиотекарь берет наудачу три учебника.
>
> Найти вероятность того, что из взятых учебников ровно один окажется в переплете.

Решение:

Вероятность, что достанут 1 в переплете из 15 = 5/15
Вероятность, что достанут 2 не в переплете = (10/14)*(9/13)
(Каким по счету достанут книгу в переплете не важно, т.к. в итоге все вероятности перемножаем и получается что учитываем это).
Общая вероятность:  (5/15)*(10/14)*(9/13)=45/273

В чем ошибка такого решения? И как решить эту задачу, подобным образом(через разложение на небольшие случаи со своими вероятностями)?

Как решить с помощью перестановок я знаю и логику понимаю. Не понимаю, в чем ошибка в приведенном решении и как правильно решить подобным способом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (Каким по счету достанут книгу в переплете не важно, т.к. в итоге все вероятности перемножаем и получается что учитываем это)

В этом и ошибка, что ты считаешь только вероятность того что книги вытащат по порядку: в переплёте → без переплёта → без переплёта. Если честно посчитать все варианты, то получится:

> <sup>5</sup>/<sub>15</sub>×<sup>10</sup>/<sub>14</sub>×<sup>9</sup>/<sub>13</sub> +  <sup>10</sup>/<sub>15</sub>×<sup>5</sup>/<sub>14</sub>×<sup>9</sup>/<sub>13</sub> + <sup>10</sup>/<sub>15</sub>×<sup>9</sup>/<sub>14</sub>×<sup>5</sup>/<sub>13</sub>
>   == <sup>45</sup>/<sub>127</sub>

т.е. в 3 раза больше.